# design patterns (builder) / attribute error

Tags: python, design-patterns, pattern-matching, builder

I want to create simple applications using builder and prototype patterns to build different houses.

(1) Modifying the program, I added the name `self._builder.name()` attribute to the create_house method, which sets the name of the house for us.
However, unexpectedly gets an error: `AttributeError: 'House1' object has no attribute 'name`'. I have no idea why this is happening since I think I have defined everything correctly.

```
    class Director():
    def __init__(self, builder):
        self._builder = builder

    def create_house(self):
        self._builder.name()
        self._builder.create_new_house()
        self._builder.add_basement()
        self._builder.add_rooms()
        self._builder.add_roof()

    def get_house(self):
        return self._builder.house


class Builder():

    def __init__(self):
        self.house = None

    def create_new_house(self):
        self.house = House()


class House1(Builder):
    def add_name(self):
        self.house.name = 'house1'

    def add_basement(self):
        self.house.basement = 'with basement'

    def add_roof(self):
        self.house.roof = 'wood roof'

    def add_rooms(self):
        self.house.rooms = 3


class House2(Builder):
    def add_name(self):
        self.house.name = 'house2'

    def add_basement(self):
        self.house.basement = 'no basement'

    def add_roof(self):
        self.house.roof = 'brick roof'

    def add_rooms(self):
        self.house.rooms = 5

class House():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.basement = None
        self.roof = None
        self.rooms = None

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Building: {} {}, {}, and {} room'.format(self.name, self.basement,
                                                           self.roof, self.rooms)


builder = WoodHouse()
director = Director(builder)
director.create_house()
house = director.get_house()
print(house)
```

(2)
by the way, I will ask if I can improve (write less) the process of calling "building" a house.
I mean this code, if I create, for example, 3 such houses, I have to repeat it, which is, however, quite unreadable and inconvenient.

```
builder = WoodHouse()
    director = Director(builder)
    director.create_house()
    house = director.get_house()
    print(house)
```

Comment: use `self._builder.add_name()` instead of `self._builder.name()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use for loop.

```py
for builder in [WoodHouse(), BrickHouse()]:
    director = Director(builder)
    director.create_house()
    house = director.get_house()
    print(house)
```